# Calling smart contracts with value using web3js and galanche

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, nodejs

I'm fairly new to Ethereum smart contracts, so this might be a stupid question, but I need someone to help me out. I've set up Galanche on my machine (MacOS 11) and written a very simple currency smart contract (I don't intend to use it as an actual currency, I just want to learn about smart contracts) using truffle.

I've compiled the contract and deployed it to my Galanche blockchain successfully.

Now, I want to interact with it using web3.js. I have set up a nodejs project and installed web3. As a first test, I ran the following script:

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const fs = require("fs");

const web3 = new Web3("http://192.168.178.49:7545");
const abi = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync("path/to/compiled/MyCoin.json").toString()
).abi;

const MyCoin = new web3.eth.Contract(
  abi,
  // My contract's address
  "0x3265aA0A2c3ac15D0eDd67BC0fa62A446c112F98"
);

(async () => {
  console.log("Starting!");
  var coinCount = await MyCoin.methods
    .getTotalCoins()
    .call({ from: "0x2d0616BF48214513f70236D59000F1b4f395a2Fd" });
  console.log("Current registered MyCoin tokens:", coinCount);
})();
```

The address `0x2d0616BF48214513f70236D59000F1b4f395a2Fd` is the first address displayed to me in  Galanche

It works as expected and returns the default amount of coins.

Now, I want to run a method called `buyMyCoin` which requires a payment. I tried running:

```js
...

MyCoin
  .methods
  .buyMyCoin
  .send(
    {
      from: '0x2d0616BF48214513f70236D59000F1b4f395a2Fd',
      value: some_amount_of_wei
    }
  );

...
```

I'd expect that when I run this node.js script again, the first part would tell me that there are `<n>` total coins, but it doesn't. It just returns the same value as the last time.

Am I doing something wrong with web3.js or is this an issue with my contract?

BTW: I didn't see any funds leave the address `0x2d0616BF48214513f70236D59000F1b4f395a2Fd` in Galanche, so I'm pretty sure it's not my contract...

I expect that somewhere I'd have to sign into this address using its public key, but I can't find anything about that in the web3.js docs that isn't very ambiguous...

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was just me being stupid! I was trying to run the transaction with an outrageously low amount of ether (4 gwei) which is, of course, so small that it can't be seen in the Ganache app.

The reason I was seeing no new coins being created was because my conversion code rounded the result to 0.

Comment: One way to debug this is emit events with data as parameters, if the transaction succeed they should appear on the transaction receipt (at least while debugging with ganache).

Comment: @Ismael Thanks! Can't believe I hadn't thought of that!